# Saving date for EFCore 3 results in System.InvalidCastException

Tags: sql-server, ef-code-first, ef-core-3.1

I use EFCore 3.1 with Code-First.
My model:

```
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime MyDate{ get; set; }
```

When using Add-Migration this results in a `date, not null` in my table.
Just as I want it.

When saving some values (`MyModel.MyDate = otherDateTime.Date.`) I get this error:

```
System.InvalidCastException
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter' to type 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDateTimeTypeMapping.ConfigureParameter(DbParameter parameter)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMapping.CreateParameter(DbCommand command, String name, Object value, Nullable`1 nullable)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.TypeMappedRelationalParameter.AddDbParameter(DbCommand command, Object value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalParameterBase.AddDbParameter(DbCommand command, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.CreateCommand(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, Guid commandId, DbCommandMethod commandMethod)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

When I remove `[Column(TypeName = "date")]` from my model AND don't do a new migration it is working.
But when I do a new migration the column is changed to datetime:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<DateTime>(
        name: "MyDate",
        table: "MyTable",
        nullable: false,
        oldClrType: typeof(DateTime),
        oldType: "date");
}
```

It seems I'm missing something. How to solve this?

Comment: The error message suggests you have some custom code somewhere that's using System.Data.SqlClient instead of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.

Comment: Thanks @AlwaysLearning The problem is with the date type vs the datetime type. I'm not doing any custom coding, the code is just mapping XML data to my database objects using AutoMapper. All other fields (int, long, decimal, string) are working fine.